# How to overcome "potentially invalid usage of this"?

Tags: javascript

I get potentially invalid usage of `this` when calling `isDataMatchingnamespace`  how to overcome and how to call `isDataMatchingnamespace` in a proper way?

```
function Client() {

    var namespace = "default";

    this.addnamespaceTodata = function(data) {
        data.namespace = namespace;
        return data;
    };

    this.isdataMatchingnamespace = function(data) {
        return data.namespace === namespace;
    };

    this.filterdatasBynamespace = function(datas) {
        var result = [];
        _.forEach(datas, function(data) {
            if (this.isdataMatchingnamespace(data)) { // I get potentially invalid usage of this so how to overcome and how to call isDataMatchingnamespace in a proper way?
                result.push(data);
            }
        });
    }
}

module.exports = Client;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is an invalid usage of `this`, since `this` is `undefined` inside that function.

underscore.js allows you to pass an optional additional argument to `forEach` to specify what `this` should be inside the function. If you want it to be the same as `this` from outside the function, then pass `this` as the third argument into [_.forEach](http://underscorejs.org/#each):

```
    _.forEach(datas, function(data) {
        if (this.isdataMatchingnamespace(data)) {
            result.push(data);
        }
    }, this); // Added ", this"
```

Answer (score 4):

there is other way also by storing this value into variable.

let's say `var _thisRef = this;` define this below `var namespace = "default";` and use `_thisRef.isdataMatchingnamespace(data)` without changing your code

your updated code as follow :

```
function Client() {

var namespace = "default";
var _thisRef = this;

this.addnamespaceTodata = function(data) {
    data.namespace = namespace;
    return data;
};

this.isdataMatchingnamespace = function(data) {
    return data.namespace === namespace;
};

this.filterdatasBynamespace = function(datas) {
    var result = [];
    _.forEach(datas, function(data) {
        if (_thisRef.isdataMatchingnamespace(data)) { // I get potentially invalid usage of this so how to overcome and how to call isDataMatchingnamespace in a proper way?
            result.push(data);
        }
    });
}
}
```

module.exports = Client;

Answer (score 0):

Another better way would be to declare a variable at a class level like:

```
export class SomeComponent {someVarible = []; }

someFunction() { const tempVar = []; _.forEach(datas, function(data) { 
                  tempVar.push(data) // now use this variable to pass or
                  assign the data 
               }, this); 
                       this.someVarible = tempVar;
                          // OR
                       otherFunction(tempVar); // where you can use your varuiable
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

es6 arrow functions does that for you automatically !

Just change the syntax to arrow function syntax

data => {
your function goes here
}